# Push to empty bare git repository fails

Tags: git, ssh, travis-ci

During a Travis CI build, I need to push my code to a potentially empty bare git repository running on machine where the code is deployed later.

On the **host machine**, I have initialized the bare git repository:

```
$ git init --bare
Initialized empty Git repository in /home/user/stuff.git/
```

SSH keys etc. are set and SSH is working.

On the **client machine** (Travis CI in this case), I do this and get an error. I have already tried purging the remote repo and initialized it again. Does anybody an idea to solve this?

```
$ git remote add $HOST user@$FQDN:stuff.git
$ git push -f $HOST $BRANCH (I have also tried without force-push)
Counting objects: 375, done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (188/188), done.
Writing objects: 100% (375/375), 3.18 MiB | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 375 (delta 171), reused 375 (delta 171)
error: Could not read 6e841a138c7b1e36db81bbbf7815336369766b81
fatal: Failed to traverse parents of commit a27fd5c2101fc69107f51c0ad895108edec3ac46
error: Could not read 6e841a138c7b1e36db81bbbf7815336369766b81
fatal: Failed to traverse parents of commit a27fd5c2101fc69107f51c0ad895108edec3ac46
To user@host:stuff.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (missing necessary objects)
error: failed to push some refs to 'user@host:stuff.git'
```

Edit2:

Environment variable reference:

```
$HOST=myserver
$FQDN=$HOST.mycompany.com
$BRANCH=master
```

Edit1:

fsck on client repo (Travis CI)

```
$ git fsck
Checking object directories: 100% (256/256), done.
Checking objects: 100% (453/453), done.
```

fsck on remote repo (before push, directly after `git init --bare`)

```
$ git fsck
notice: HEAD points to an unborn branch (master)
Checking object directories: 100% (256/256), done.
notice: No default references
```

fsck on remote repo (after push)

```
$ git fsck
notice: HEAD points to an unborn branch (master)
Checking object directories: 100% (256/256), done.
Checking objects: 100% (453/453), done.
notice: No default references
dangling commit 95d0bbce235f8317f849a0766cca6604ac334c21
```

Comment: Can you try running `git fsck` in repository just to make sure that it's all fine and working before you push? I don't think this is anything to do with your remote but a problem with your local repository.

Comment: Hi @NoufalIbrahim ! I've added the git fsck outputs

Comment: What are the values of $HOST and $BRANCH for which you're pushing?

Comment: $HOST is just a remote name we have. So we have a server running on myserver.somethingeelse.com, where the $HOST part will be "myserver". $BRANCH has the value of "master" (everything without quotes)

$FQDN is "$HOST.somethingelse.com"

Answer (score 1):

I have found a solution.

Travis CI seems to do a shallow clone on build. At least Codeship is doing it to increase git clone operations: https://codeship.com/documentation/faq/push-to-remote-repositories/

So before pushing to the bare repo, I do

```
git fetch --unshallow || true
git fetch origin "+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*"
...
git push -f $HOST $BRANCH
```

Now the `git push` runs smoothly. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: This seems sensible to me. The necessary objects to push and create a full clone were not available. That's why the push failed. I thought it was because your repository was corrupt which is why I suggested the `fsck` but apparently, it wasn't a full clone.

Comment: I put the first two lines from OP into my `before_script` in my `.travis.yml` file and it solved my problem.